# Prerender dc.js on server, maintain interactive events on client

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, prerender

Title says it all: I prerender a chart on a server using dc.js and node.js and return the SVG back to the client. The SVG looks like the following: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e2f7d237bcc784cfe97d

At the client, I simply write the returned SVG into a div

```
var svg = prerenderChart(...)
document.getElementById("dc_plot").innerHTML = svg;
```

The result looks pretty okay, the only problem is that the "track lines" are not appearing when I hover a data point. It should look like the following: http://s2.postimg.org/jqs37yird/3837933.png

I can see in the SVG, that the blue dot and the dotted grey lines are there, but they will not be set visible on a mouseover. I suppose it has something to do with dc.js's mouseover event listener which is not bound to the SVG in dc_plot (dc.js, d3.js and crossfilter.js are added at the client side). Of course I could write my own event listener but maybe there's an easier solution?

Comment: You aren't going to be able to have the interactive features of dc.js unless you run it on the client - these are part of the javascript library and won't be available in the exported SVG.  You would have to either add the functionality yourself, or find a way to have dc.js run on the client.

Comment: Yes, but the dc.js library is already added at the client side. So I just need a way to tell dc.js that the SVG in dc_plot should behave like it was produced by dc.js on the client side but with the limitation that data processing and crossfiltering happens on the server - is this possible?

Comment: Not really, because as dc creates the SVG it is adding mouse event handlers which are lost when you export the SVG to a file (and can't be saved in a file format). The usual solution to this problem is to run crossfilter on the server and dc on the client, but that is some work and I don't know of a public example.

Comment: Okay, I saved the complete page node.js renders into a file. The output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1eb4d851fa58c27203b2
But there are no javascript events which means, they must be taken directly from the dc.js library